# Change background color on image hover

Tags: html, css

How would I make it so that if you hover over an image, the entire image changes to the color black (the image link must be in the HTML tag as the sizes and images are different)?

Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.floral-directory.com/flower.gif" class="image" />
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  width: 250px;
}

.image:hover {
  background: #000000;
}
```

Comment: You can't change entire image. As the name says, it's a `background-color`, not foreground. The current css will just make bg color black on hover, but maintaning the image above

Comment: So how would I make the color in the foreground?

Comment: Would it be okay to hide the image, and display a black div instead?

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to do this is to wrap the `img` element in another, for example a `span`:

```
<span class="imgWrap">
    <img src="http://www.floral-directory.com/flower.gif" class="image" />
</span>
```

And couple that to the CSS:

```css
.imgWrap {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.imgWrap:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}

img:hover,
.imgWrap:hover img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PbvFr/).

And, if you'd like to make it a little prettier, using transitions to fade in/out:

```css
.imgWrap {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.imgWrap img {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

.imgWrap:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}

img:hover,
.imgWrap:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PbvFr/1/).

Comment: Good way of doing it with css and html only.

Comment: Thanks! I would have preferred to use `::before`/`::after` pseudo-elements (despite cross-browser limitations) in order to avoid adding elements as CSS-hooks; but unfortunately `img` elements can't contain anything, so they wouldn't work.

Comment: Why are you using both img:hover and .imgWrap:hover img? Seems to work fine with just the hover event on the .imgWrap http://jsfiddle.net/uAQMt/

Comment: Mainly because I'm used to JavaScript where the child being `mouseenter`-ed removes the `mouseenter` from the ancestor. It's just a hangover, and does no harm, I think.

Comment: To get rid of the parent extra height (4px to be exact) just give the image `display: block;` http://jsfiddle.net/uAQMt/9/

Answer (score 0):

The HTML

```
<div class="change_bg">
  <img src="http://eofdreams.com/data_images/dreams/image/image-07.jpg" >
</div>
```

The CSS

```css
.change_bg img{
    max-width : 300px;
}

.change_bg{
    width : 300px;
    height : 300px;
    float:left;
}

.change_bg img:hover{
    visibility : hidden;
}

.change_bg:hover {
    background : #bc7d89;
}
```

Live Example @ http://cdpn.io/Bmthc